# why different question marked as duplicate (on emulation and installing exe)?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I don't understand why this question [How to run neogeo games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301814/how-to-run-neogeo-games) is marked of duplicate of this question [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-also-games) ?

The first one ask about *emulation in Ubuntu*, where there is an emulation in ubuntu without installing windows specific like mednafen for example.

The second one ask *how to install Windows games*, and of course the answers are related to that.

If it was a different question and different answer why mark it as duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Because the people doing the closing got it wrong.

I've reopened it.

Comment: Please, make it bold that is likely to **explode** :P.